# What happened to the escape pods on the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, a-new-hope, millennium-falcon

In ANH, an Imperial officer reports to Darth Vader regarding the recently captured *Millennium Falcon*:

> There's no one on board, sir. According to the log, the crew abandoned ship right after takeoff. It must be a decoy, sir. **Several of the escape pods have been jettisoned.**

*What happened to the escape pods?* All of the crew and passengers that were aboard the ship when it departed from Tatooine are still there at this point (only hiding), and there was no discussion of jettisoning anything in a pod or jettisoning any pods as a distraction. **Is anything known about when and/or where the escape pods were actually jettisoned? Does supplementary material establish that Han and/or Chewie intentionally jettisoned some empty pods to make it *appear* that the ship had been abandoned (and probably falsified the ship's log at the same time)?**

Comment: It takes much longer to check that no escape pods have been used, than to read the log. The officer reports almost immediately after Falcon is captured, he refers to the log. So I believe it was falsified.

Comment: The log states **when** they abandoned the ship, not if the pods are still there or not (which can be seen with a visual inspection).

Comment: Knowing the general state of things onboard Falcon, some pods may be already missing (mentioned jettisoning of Jabba's cargo). So maybe the inspection crew saw the missing pods and did not doubt the log records

Comment: I doubt they were jettissioned recently. The first thing to know about the Millennium Falcon is what a piece of junk it is, so the escape pods were probably lost years ago and never worth replacing.

Comment: I always assumed they'd been jettisoned many adventures ago, and never replaced, the way people don't always replace the expensive air bag assemblies after an accident.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove some of the extra questions. If you want, you can re-ask those as new questions.

Comment: all that can be known under current canon is that the logs says they were jettisoned.  there isn't any real proof that there were even escape pods to jettison in the first place.  just that YT-1300's are able to have escape pods, and the logs say they were jettisoned shortly after takeoff.

Comment: Erm... they escaped.

Comment: I also wonder what happened to that middle piece between the “forked fins” on the front of the ship. In Solo, something fills in between the “fins”.

Comment: @Miss it was explained in that film. It was ejected.

Comment: Ah that’s right. It’s been way too long since I saw it last. lol

Comment: Like much of Han's material wealth, lost years ago in a game of Sabaac.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Han jettisoned real escape pods. We see him doing so in the film's (canon) junior novelisation.

> “You might want to jettison escape pods,” Ben said as Chewie stood and started to usher them out of the cockpit.
> “Do you know how expensive those are to replace?” Han asked, outraged.
> “More or less valuable than your life?” was the calm response.
> Han was still muttering about old men and their stupid questions when he turned back to the console and went to work writing up a quick notation in the captain’s log. *Abandoned ship upon entering the Alderaan system due to safety concerns*. **With a resigned sigh, he launched the empty escape pods. He listened to the pop and hiss as their restraints released and sent them spiraling into space.**
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

He evidently never recovered them from the Alderaan debris field since the five

> CEC Class-1 Escape Pods
>
> <sup><sub>[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)</sub></sup>

he was using at this time were replaced by

> ESCAPE POD CLASS A9-40
>
> <sup><sub>[Star Wars: The Last Jedi: Expanded Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sub></sup>

by the time of The Last Jedi.

Comment: This is a great answer, however this isn't really *canon* canon. It's merely *a* canon. As LucasFilm themselves say: "When it comes to absolute canon, the real story of Star Wars, you must turn to the films themselves—and only the films. Even novelizations are interpretations of the film..."

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Actually that quote only refers to the *original film novelisations* (those written pre-2014); https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=x01ODwAAQBAJ&pg=PT888&lpg=PT888&dq=%22Even+novelizations+are+interpretations+of+the+film%22&source=bl&ots=DGIcThvIYC&sig=5BfRw9jm20lMDkfS17gJR-GmpT0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJwvfq-7raAhWrB8AKHTyZDK0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Even%20novelizations%20are%20interpretations%20of%20the%20film%22&f=false

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - [The quote](https://tinyurl.com/y9lvhphb) you should be looking at is this one from 2014; "*To be clear, there is no 'new EU.' There is only the established EU--hereafter known as Star Wars Legends, and the main, canon storyline, which includes the films, The Clone Wars and Rebels television shows, and the new novels beginning this September with A NEW DAWN. It sounds like a minor thing to point out, but it's significant in the fact that even the term "EU" always meant it was outside the main, whereas now, all new material will be part of a unified whole.*"

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think it's quite silly to insist a junior novelisation is on the same level of canon as the original films, but that's *technically* Disney's stance right now.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - The junior novels are (for the most part) identical to the adult novels, just shorter and with fewer big words that have been added in to make adult readers feel smart

Comment: The first chapter or so is here. I can't say I agree with your assessment of it being "identical to the adult novels": http://books.disney.com/content/uploads/2015/05/ANewHope.pdf

The first pages of adult novelisation can be found here: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0345341465

I don't agree that Alan Dean Foster used "big words... to make adult readers feel smart", either.

Answer (score 9):

There's no George Lucas-approved canonical* answer to this, but I think if there's any logic, it's in the dialogue. As the Stormtrooper says:

> **According to the log...**

Visually we never saw anything resembling escape pods or locations where escape pods could be. Indeed there's no visual difference in the Millennium Falcon on Tatooine to when it's captured on the Death Star.

From this, I think we can safely say it's a simple lie. There were no escape pods, but Han Solo hacked his logs to suggest there were, to give the impression the vessel was deserted. In fact, I'd even wager that this is probably a ploy that Solo and Chewbacca have used in their careers as smugglers before.

---

* Disney, the current copyright holder, has other ideas, however. They have decided that any novelization or TV shows that are released from September 2014 onwards are now completely canon. This means that the [*Star Wars Junior Novels*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Hope-Junior-Novel/dp/1405285427) (2017) are considered canon, which (according to that version of the story) means that Han did indeed eject the escape pods.

Comment: There is a canonical answer to this.

Comment: Alas, your answer still contains an inaccuracy. Post-2014 there are no canon "levels", merely Canon and Legends (e.g. not canon). Where things *directly disagree* with the films, we assume that they're simply a writing error. Where they elaborate, those facts are still canon.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, a big corporation tells you what to think. I'd rather go with the artist, myself.

Comment: The original artist isn't in control of the story anymore - he sold that right (which is great for him). Disney and the Lucasfilm Story Group soley determine what is or isn't 'officially' part of the Star Wars story now, and they have established that, to the best of their abilities, any comics, books (YA or adult), certain video games (single player storylines), TV shows, and films are all intended to be consistent with each other and are 'canon'. There are many artists now - we should go with them and the people they work for who own the property.

Comment: Your answer could be changed from *George Lucas canon* to "Legends" canon and it might be accurate under that scope.

Comment: @NKCampbell Deary dear. This is what art has come down to? A big corporation tells you what to accept, and you wholeheartedly follow? Lawyers be damned!

Comment: For the purposes of this site, and what is an acceptable answer from an objective, in-universe point of view - yes, this is what it comes down to. Feel free to have the discussion on Reddit where opinions, not objectivity is the norm

Comment: @NKCampbell I understand the need to point out Disney's perspective on this, but this is a website for fans, not a legal document. As such there is more leeway than simply regurgitating the stance that a team of lawyers has decided will result in the most profit for their corporation. In this instance we have a clearly identifiable author, and even though Disney has decided his "canon" no longer exists, we know it was done without that creator's consent. As a fan, the author of the work still has a valid say in the matter, despite what a boardroom decided.

Comment: true, this is a website for fans, however, the intent is to provide accurate answers under the current known scope of a work - in this case - canon. Which, again, in this case, is decided by a group of artists and executives, not the original creator. And again, if you simply edit the answer to indicate that the information relates to what is now known as "Legends" information (ie - the old Expanded Universe, pre-Disney, etc....), then the answer would be perfectly fine since the question includes the tag 'Legends'.

Comment: Here are some relevant meta (ie - community agreed upon rules...er..more like guidelines) related to the subject: Most importantly: *"The spirit of the site is about studying works of speculative fiction in the context of canon."*

https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10298/why-is-canon-important | https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/star-wars-canon-disney-revisions | https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/are-we-really-fit-to-give-judgement-on-what-is-canon

Comment: @NKCampbell I'm sorry, but we're just going to have to agree to disagree on this. I see absolutely no reason to censor other points of view, as you appear to be tenaciously fighting for. I've accepted the argument for Disney's take, but to insist that COPYRIGHT HOLDER usurps the ARTIST, in every way, to the point where the artist's voice is no longer considered valid, is just crazy to me.

Comment: I'm not saying your argument is incorrect on the whole, but it *is* incorrect for *this* site. You're missing the point. Also - your answer is almost purely conjecture - which isn't siding with the intent of the artist at all. If you go by a strict interpretation of the script - "according to the logs..." the pods were jettisoned. There is no reason to think anything other than that happened given the text and film. Pure speculation on your part to say that Chewie rigged the logs, the pods weren't there to begin with, etc....

Comment: @NKCampbell I beginning to think you're trolling now. At first you argue that "The original artist isn't in control of the story anymore" and now you're complaining that maybe Chewie didn't rig the logs. I'm done with this.

Comment: 1) The original artist isn't in control anymore: that's an objective fact. 2) The idea of Chewie rigging the logs is speculation on your part - can you prove that speculation from the script / film? No - all that is said is "according to the logs" - there is no reason from the text / film to think that means Chewie (why not Han? Or Kenobi? Or R2-D2?) did anything. The logs say they were jettisoned. Period. Either reference Disney canon or Legends canon. Speculation is irrelevant

Comment: @NKCampbell Ok, you are trolling. Reported.

Comment: hardly trolling - not only have I referenced the applicable meta (ie community standards) related to your answer, I have also offered a suggestion on how to modify it to make it an acceptable answer. This site doesn't generally acknowledge speculation as an answer, rather trying for objective fact. I'm not sure what is trolling about pointing all of that out. Other than you just don't like it. Sorry bub

Comment: @NKCampbell You're literally making things up about my answer to continue an argument. I call that trolling. Not to mention that, given we're talking about fiction, almost all answers on this site include some sort of speculation. The meta post you linked to is about including fanfic in an answer, which is why it's rated so poorly by the community.

Comment: @NKCampbell I would direct you to a meta post with more standing within the community about what constitutes "canon", and how it should be treated: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2027/4380

Comment: .....okay. You'll notice that the last link I included in my meta links is to the same one you linked to. Whatever. You clearly aren't understanding what I'm saying. Good day

Answer (score 0):

In the Star Wars wiki, there is an entry that "At the advice of Obi-Wan Kenobi, Han Solo jettisoned the escape pods of the Millennium Falcon when the ship was caught in the tractor beam of the Death Star", but no evidence can be found in either the movie script or book. This may be inferred since Kenobi mentions "there are always alternatives to fighting" as the Falcon is pulled towards the Death Star. Were the pods still on the ship? Maybe, since only the ship's log was referenced. The full scan did not happen because the Death Star techs were captured by Solo.

Comment: I'm not convinced that a scanner tech is really required to determine whether a ship's escape pods have been used.  Should be pretty easy -- go to wherever they are and look for them. The *Falcon* may have been heavily modified, but was at least originally of a fairly common type, so it should be pretty easy to work out where they were supposed to be.

Comment: True, but neither a full scan or physical inspection was done. In the book, they remotely opened the cargo doors, inspected the hold, then went to the cockpit. From there, a soldier read the ship's log and reported what he found. Vader ordered a full search and dismissed the soldiers. In the book, it was a Sergeant who read the ship's log and no techs were in the initial boarding. The tech crew went in alone and were quickly overpowered. Yes, the soldiers could have done a physical inspection on the pods, but this could have been a "not my job" scenario.

Comment: @Jules, While a scanner isn't needed to see if the pods are gone or not, it might reveal other information such as when it happened, in what system, mass of contents, etc. By examining the friction marks it might show that the pods were empty and only jettisoned recently (depth of, and lack of residue in, the scratches).